# How to navigate to main page after lottie splash.json completed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

How to navigate the main page after the Lottie animation completed in a flutter when I run the code it shows the Lottie animation repeatedly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `AnimationController` and in `Lottie` `onLoaded` call `AnimationController` `forward().whenComplete` then you can do `Navigator.push` 
code snippet

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
  }
...  
Lottie.asset(
            'assets/LottieLogo1.json',
            controller: _controller,
            onLoaded: (composition) {
              _controller
                ..duration = composition.duration
                ..forward().whenComplete(() => Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                    ));
            },
          ),
```

To run working demo, you need this file https://github.com/xvrh/lottie-flutter/blob/master/example/assets/LottieLogo1.json
working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Lottie.asset(
            'assets/LottieLogo1.json',
            controller: _controller,
            onLoaded: (composition) {
              _controller
                ..duration = composition.duration
                ..forward().whenComplete(() => Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                    ));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Second Page")));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AnimationController with a stateListener

```
class SplashView extends StatefulWidget {
  final SplashBloc splashBloc;

  const SplashView({super.key, required this.splashBloc});

  @override
  SplashViewState createState() => SplashViewState();
}

class SplashViewState extends State<SplashView>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
      vsync: this,
    );

    controller.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        // Notify the Bloc that the animation is completed
        widget.splashBloc.add(SplashAnimationCompleteEvent());
      }
    });
    widget.splashBloc.add(SplashAnimationReadyEvent());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<SplashBloc, SplashState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state.isAnimationReady) {
          controller.forward();
        } else if (state.isAnimationCompleted) {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, RouteName.welcome);
        }
      },
      child: Container(
          color: AppColors.brandDarkBlue,
          child: Center(
            child: Lottie.asset(
              AppAssets.splashAnimation,
              controller: controller,
              key: const Key("loader"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
     );
  }
}
```